# How do you shrink an image in half in Java without using Graphics2D?

Tags: java, image, colors, graphics, resize

I need to write a program that shrinks an image in half without using any libraries other than Java Graphics and Java Color. I wrote one earlier with Graphics2D that looked like this --

```java
public static void shrink(String orig, String convert) throws Exception { //Ahh damn we needed one from the red group
                BufferedImage bufferedimg = null;
                File f = new File(orig);
                bufferedimg = ImageIO.read(f);

                int width = bufferedimg.getWidth();
                int height = bufferedimg.getHeight();

                int finalWidth = width/2;
                int finalHeight = height/2;

                BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(bufferedimg, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight, null);
                g.dispose();

                f = new File(convert);
                ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "png", f);
        }
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Image.getScaledInstance() resizes the image, although it generally won't return a BufferedImage.

Comment: maybe with g.scale(double x, double y) before calling g.drawImage

Comment: You can always get the pixel array and implement the scaling yourself. But why not using the standard Java2D libraries? Is this a school assignment?